# Method Rows of object Global Failed

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an access button that opens 4 excel files, formats them and then imports the data, well that's the idea anyway. I get a run-time error 1004 Method Rows of object Global failed when it tries to run the code a second time.

I have this code 4 different times but for each Dim has a number at the end, example the 2nd sub has wkSht2, sub 3 has wkSht3 and so on. when the code gets to sub 2 I get the Global failed at this line

LastRow2 = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

```
Sub xlAPS1()
    
    Dim myApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wkBk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wkSht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set myApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wkBk = myApp.Workbooks.Open("PATH\WORKBOOK.xlsx")
    Set wkSht = wkBk.Worksheets(1)
    
    With wkSht
        LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Rows(LastRow).Delete
        .Rows("1:27").Delete
        .Columns("A:AQ").ClearFormats
        .Rows("2:2").Delete
        .Columns("AO:AZ").Delete
        .Columns("AH:AM").Delete
        .Columns("AD:AD").Delete
        .Columns("AB:AB").Delete
        .Columns("Z:Z").Delete
        .Columns("V:X").Delete
        .Columns("L:T").Delete
        .Columns("I:I").Delete
        .Columns("G:G").Delete
        .Columns("E:E").Delete
        .Range("A1").Value = "Today"
        .Range("A2").Value = Date
        .Range("A2:A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        .Range("H1").Value = "Percentage"
        .Range("Q1").Value = "Comments"
        .Range("R1").Value = "Error Correct"
        .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    
    myApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    wkBk.Save
    wkBk.Close True
    myApp.Quit
    Set wkSht = Nothing
    Set wkBk = Nothing
    Set myApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Missing a period before `Range`. Also missing several periods in `.Range("A2:A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)`.

Comment: are you saying i am missing a it should be more like this?
LastRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row and 

I added a period before Range and Cells in this one is that right?
.Range("A2:A2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A2:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

Comment: You missed a period in front of `Rows.Count`. Best to qualify every `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, or `Columns` call.

Comment: you are a life save! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to BigBen, i was missing periods in a few places but here is the updated code that worked for me. Thanks Ben

```
Dim myApp As Excel.Application
Dim wkBk As Excel.Workbook
Dim wkSht As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set myApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wkBk = myApp.Workbooks.Open("PATH\EXCELWORKBOOK.xlsx")
Set wkSht = wkBk.Worksheets(1)

With wkSht
    LastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Rows(LastRow).Delete
    .Rows("1:27").Delete
    .Columns("A:AQ").ClearFormats
    .Rows("2:2").Delete
    .Columns("AO:AZ").Delete
    .Columns("AH:AM").Delete
    .Columns("AD:AD").Delete
    .Columns("AB:AB").Delete
    .Columns("Z:Z").Delete
    .Columns("V:X").Delete
    .Columns("L:T").Delete
    .Columns("I:I").Delete
    .Columns("G:G").Delete
    .Columns("E:E").Delete
    '.Cells(LastRow).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete
    .Range("A1").Value = "Today"
    .Range("A2").Value = Date
    .Range("A2:A2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    .Range("H1").Value = "Percentage"
    .Range("Q1").Value = "Comments"
    .Range("R1").Value = "Error Correct"
    .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    '.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End With

myApp.DisplayAlerts = False
wkBk.Save
wkBk.Close True
myApp.Quit
Set wkSht = Nothing
Set wkBk = Nothing
Set myApp = Nothing
```